# An instance of PagingSource was re-used when Pager expected to create a new [Compose+Paging3]

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-paging-3, jetpack-compose-navigation

How to invalidate PagingSource when new items added/updated?

How to observe any changes to room database records?

**Agenda**:

I was trying to add new records in every 10 secs and wants to reflect those changes into UI.

but failing to implement it.

**Errors**:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An instance of PagingSource was re-used when Pager expected to create a new
                                                                                                    instance. Ensure that the pagingSourceFactory passed to Pager always returns a
                                                                                                    new instance of PagingSource.
```

Kotlin Class

```
class ArticlePagedUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ArticleRepository
) {

    operator fun invoke(): Flow<PagingData<ArticleEntity>> {
        Log.d("GoogleIO","Invalidate Paging 3")
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                prefetchDistance = 40
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                repository.articlesPaged
            }
        ).flow
    }

    suspend fun addArticle(articleEntity: ArticleEntity) {
        delay(1000)
        repository.addArticle(articleEntity)
    }

}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
interface ArticleDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM article_entity")
    fun getAllArticlesPaged() : PagingSource<Int, ArticleEntity>

    @Insert
    suspend fun addArticle(articleEntity: ArticleEntity)
}
```

Paging 3 Outcome with new changes reflection on UI everytime database updated.

Comment: Where is PagingSource?. You should provide a new instance of PagingSource each time. Check if repository.articlesPaged is the same instance. check https://genicsblog.com/gouravkhunger/pagination-in-android-room-database-using-the-paging-3-library MainPagingSource. You don't need the if conditions. Also use collect with lifecyle

Comment: @Raghunandan How to detect data change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by implementing below condition

```
@Composable
fun ArticleContent(viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

val lazyArticleItems = viewModel.articlesFlows.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

if (lazyArticleItems.loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading && lazyArticleItems.itemCount < 1) {
    Log.d("GoogleIO", "LazyArticleIsLoading")
} else {
    Log.d("GoogleIO", "LazyArticleIsLoaded :: :: ")
    LazyColumn {
        items(
            count = lazyArticleItems.itemCount
        ) { index: Int ->
            ArticleItem(lazyArticleItems[index]!!)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**